# Which carriers support iOS 10's voicemail transcription?

Tags: iphone, ios, cellular-carriers, visual-voicemail

I'm curious because I don't see any text under my voicemails when I tap on them, but I've seen videos of that being what you do, and I've read that it doesn't require any activation. I don't see why it would be limited to the iPhone 6s, iPhone 6s Plus, or the iPhone SE (I have an iPhone 6). I've narrowed it down to my carrier (AT&T).

Is there a place where I can see if my carrier supports voicemail transcription?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know what phone you have or what carrier you're using, so for the sake of discussion, I looked up my own. My iPhone 6 Plus 16Gb is not capable of "Voicemail to Text" with Sprint. They said it was a hardware/software issue, not a carrier issue.

Answer (score 3):

Voicemail transcription (beta) is available on iPhone 6s, iPhone 6s Plus, and iPhone SE with Siri language set to English (United States or Canada).

Comment: Just to clarify, this means *only* on the 6s, 6s Plus, and SE, right?

Comment: Also just highlighting that Siri must be turned on for this to work.